# Counting words which aren't starting with given letter

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

So I wrote this function in Lisp which counts how many words aren't starting with a given letter in a list.
However I now need to edit it and not use "let" in my function (but keep "char" and "string").
Feeling a bit blocked as I've started Lisp not so long go ! Anyone would be able to help me ?

example :
`(others 'n '(art nose foot nose take silence never)) => 4`

Thats what I did but need to remove the "let" :

```
(defun others (x liste)
  (let ((c (char (string x) 0)))
    (cond
      ((not liste) 0)
      ((char= (char (string (car liste)) 0) c) (others x (cdr liste)))
      (t (+ 1 (others x (cdr liste)))) ) ) )
```

Comment: the function to test for an empty list is called `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use an `&aux` variable in the argument list. This lets you bind variables in the function much like `let` does. This is pretty much a way to use `let` at the start of the function without explicitly using `let`.

```
(defun others (x liste &aux (c (char (string x) 0)))
   (cond
      ((not liste) 0)
      ((char= (char (string (car liste)) 0) c) (others x (cdr liste)))
      (t (+ 1 (others x (cdr liste))))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I thought about &aux but wasn't sure on how to use it with char !

Comment: @valerie Since c is only used once, another solution is to not bind a variable at all and just substitute `(char (string x) 0)` where c is used.

Answer (score 2):

Another built-in way is this:

```
> (count 'n
         '(art nose foot nose take silence never)
         :test #'(lambda (a b)
                   (string/= a b :end1 1 :end2 1)))
-> 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an iterative version:

```lisp
(loop for word in '("art" "nose" "foot" "nose" "take" "silence" "never")
      for c = #\n
      count (not (char= c (char word 0))))
```

(loop can be learned by example with https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html)